# GPO block executables from running from redirected folders

Tags: windows, security, group-policy

I am currently using GPO (Computer>Windows>Security>Software>Additional) to lock down several file types from running in places like C:\ and `%appdata%` and `%userprofile%`. My issue is that certain folders like "Documents" are redirected to shares while "Downloads" are not. Using `%userprofile%\*\*.exe` I can block executables in "Downloads" (not redirected) but I CANNOT block items in "Desktop" (redirected). I have tried `\\profiles\*\Desktop\*.exe` but that does not work either. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You've got it backwards. You should block EXE's from everywhere, except on whitelisted paths.

But to answer your question directly, you will need to specify the redirected path in the rule, not the original path. That's why your rule is not working.

Comment: The path has variables. I can't create GPOs for 5K users * 4 folders.

Comment: More specifically, I need something similar to `\\profiles\*\Desktop\*.exe` but that works.

Comment: You don't need to be that specific. Just block the entire share.

Comment: There are folders within each user profile that have items that do need to be run including login scripts. That's not a practical solution.

Comment: It sounds more like you have an over-complicated setup. Why are you running exe's from user profile folders?

Comment: Does it matter for the purpose of my question? It is complex.

Comment: It depends. Do you want more help? Without any further information, I have no further advice to give. Right now I still stand by my two comments: "You've got it backwards", and "you have an over-complicated setup". It's only going to get more complicated if you go farther down this path. But all of that is based on the little slice of your network I've seen here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Software Restriction Policies, since it's [deprecated in Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-1803-removed-features#features-were-no-longer-developing) I recommend you to take a look at [AppLocker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/what-is-applocker) and implement it on a lab environment first.

You'll be able to do what you want with it since it's blocking everything by default, however you can add trusted path/patterns easily.